# Magento patch bug

Tags: magento-1, patches, install-script, bug

I just was examining the `PATCH_SUPEE-3941_EE_1.14.0.1_v1.sh` ([download page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/download)) which changes `downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Packager.php` file and noticed that there is a strange lines:

[image]

Is this a dev typo? Why do we need 2 identical lines?
Additionally I have [submitted a bug report](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/347).

Comment: Be careful with this screenshot, you are not allowed to share this :(

Comment: Why not? I can provide it as text, but I suppose it would look better in diff view.

Comment: Sorry. Misunderstanding. It is magentos copyright and they don't allow you to share patches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right. They deleted the wrong line. It doesn't make sense to remove the dir creation and instead have two lines setting `$source`.

Let's see what they answer on the ticket.